# trained model for image classification always returns the 0th index in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

I've used transfer learning to classify an image(classify between ants and bees) tbvh i just copy pasted the whole exact code available in  [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html) and saved the model using pycharm ide later load the same and pass a single image to predict the output but instead of the actual output i keep getting the same zeroth index value defined inside my 'classes'

> this is the code base of the whole model

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import numpy as np
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import os
import copy
import pickle


def main():
    data_transforms = {
        'train': transforms.Compose([
            transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ]),
        'val': transforms.Compose([
            transforms.Resize(256),
            transforms.CenterCrop(224),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ]),
    }

    data_dir = 'hymenoptera_data'
    image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                              data_transforms[x])
                      for x in ['train', 'val']}
    dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                                  shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
                   for x in ['train', 'val']}
    dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
    class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    def imshow(inp, title=None):
        """Imshow for Tensor."""
        inp = inp.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0))
        mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
        std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        inp = std * inp + mean
        inp = np.clip(inp, 0, 1)
        plt.imshow(inp)
        if title is not None:
            plt.title(title)
        plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated

    # Get a batch of training data
    inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders['train']))

    # Make a grid from batch
    out = torchvision.utils.make_grid(inputs)

    imshow(out, title=[class_names[x] for x in classes])

    def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
        since = time.time()

        best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
        best_acc = 0.0

        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            print(f'Epoch {epoch}/{num_epochs - 1}')
            print('-' * 10)

            # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
            for phase in ['train', 'val']:
                if phase == 'train':
                    model.train()  # Set model to training mode
                else:
                    model.eval()  # Set model to evaluate mode

                running_loss = 0.0
                running_corrects = 0

                # Iterate over data.
                for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                    inputs = inputs.to(device)
                    labels = labels.to(device)

                    # zero the parameter gradients
                    optimizer.zero_grad()

                    # forward
                    # track history if only in train
                    with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                        outputs = model(inputs)
                        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
                        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

                        # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                        if phase == 'train':
                            loss.backward()
                            optimizer.step()

                    # statistics
                    running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                    running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
                if phase == 'train':
                    scheduler.step()

                epoch_loss = running_loss / dataset_sizes[phase]
                epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / dataset_sizes[phase]

                print(f'{phase} Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f} Acc: {epoch_acc:.4f}')

                # deep copy the model
                if phase == 'val' and epoch_acc > best_acc:
                    best_acc = epoch_acc
                    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

            print()

        time_elapsed = time.time() - since
        print(f'Training complete in {time_elapsed // 60:.0f}m {time_elapsed % 60:.0f}s')
        print(f'Best val Acc: {best_acc:4f}')

        # load best model weights
        model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
        return model

    def visualize_model(model, num_images=6):
        was_training = model.training
        model.eval()
        images_so_far = 0
        fig = plt.figure()

        with torch.no_grad():
            for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(dataloaders['val']):
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                outputs = model(inputs)
                _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

                for j in range(inputs.size()[0]):
                    images_so_far += 1
                    ax = plt.subplot(num_images // 2, 2, images_so_far)
                    ax.axis('off')
                    ax.set_title(f'predicted: {class_names[preds[j]]}')
                    imshow(inputs.cpu().data[j])

                    if images_so_far == num_images:
                        model.train(mode=was_training)
                        return
            model.train(mode=was_training)

    model_ft = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    num_ftrs = model_ft.fc.in_features
    # Here the size of each output sample is set to 2.
    # Alternatively, it can be generalized to nn.Linear(num_ftrs, len(class_names)).
    model_ft.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)

    model_ft = model_ft.to(device)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    # Observe that all parameters are being optimized
    optimizer_ft = optim.SGD(model_ft.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

    # Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
    exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_ft, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

    ###
    # save using pickle

    # pickle.dump(model_ft, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))

    ###
    # save using torch
    # def save_model(model, best_acc):
    #     state = {
    #         'model': model_ft,
    #         'acc': best_acc,
    #     }

    torch.save(model_ft, './best_model.pth')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now loading the saved model and passing an image

```
# to be worked on

from __future__ import print_function, division

import torch

import numpy as np

from torchvision import transforms

import PIL.Image as Image

classes = [

    "ants",
    "bees",
]

# loading model
model = torch.load('best_model.pth')

# transform the image
mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

image_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224,)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(torch.Tensor(mean), torch.Tensor(std))

])


def classify(model, image_transforms, image_path, classes):
    model = model.eval()
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    image = image_transforms(image).float()
    image = image.unsqueeze(0)

    output = model(image)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)

    print(classes[predicted.item()])

classify(model,image_transforms,"beeimage.jpg",classes)
```

> output of which should be `bees` but instead it is returning `ants`

> output for the same is

```
C:\Users\prasa\Desktop\DL\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\prasa\Desktop\DL\callmod1.py 
ants

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

well i realized there is a silly mistake i did , i shouldve debug it before posting here.
It was that my function `train_model` was never called in the training model  code. As a result of which it was never trained and acted upon the pretrained sets

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).